# Why do the images move when clicked in html and css? How to prevent it?

Tags: html, css

I am completely new to html and css. [This](http://booksinfinite.net) is my first website. When someone clicks on an image under some category, it moves while using chrome. I would like to prevent it. Please help.

Comment: Does adding `* {outline:0;}` to your CSS fix what you're talking about? If not, what images are you talking about? What you linked to has no images.

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code on JSFiddle or something similar.. It'll be easier to help you.

Comment: http://booksinfinite.net/library/science%20and%20technology.html like the images in this one. These images move only while using chrome, not with firefox.

Comment: And a hint: does not use divs between uls and lis. It's bad html. :)

Comment: add some parts of your code. or a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `books li` selector is positioned relative:

```
.books li{
    display: inline;
    position: relative; /* remove this */
    top: 100px;
    left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: You will need to fix the padding and margin above. There is quite a lot of similar questions on Stack Overflow relating to chrome and relative positioning. Glad it helped

Comment: Thanks! I will improve upon the code.